# is the autocomplete property, a standard html property?

Tags: html, browser, autocomplete

I want to understand that "autocomplete"  is a standard property or not?!
like this:

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

and can i use this in FF,IE,Opera,....?
if yes,which browsers and which version of those support that?
is it a browser cross property?

**Regards.**

**Sam**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it was part of webforms 2 (html 4.01). I'm pretty sure everyone supports it

http://www.w3.org/Submission/web-forms2/#the-autocomplete

also listed in the html 5 spec

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute

Answer (score 0):

this may have the answer for you :
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_AUTOCOMPLETE.html
(use it, but don't rely on it)